# Laravel 8, why do I have to route:cache for every change I made in routes/web.php?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-8

I've been working on different projects with laravel 8 and the 'problem' (if it is really a problem) is that for every change I made on `routes/web.php` I have to `route:cache` every freaking time.

If I make a change and `route:list`, the new changes will not be displayed.
Is this thing correct or is there any bug? If so is there any way not to `route:cache` or `route:clear` for every change that is made on `web.php`?

Thank you! happy coding!

Comment: I work with laravel 8 and I don't have this issue, there's something wrong!

Comment: I dont know but in 3 projects the same issue and this is crazy...

Comment: Are you calling `php artisan route:cache` via a composer script or deployment hook? Or is this happening locally across all 3 projects?

Comment: What do you mean, im doing in it in laravel way manually: php artisan route:cache

Comment: locally happening

Comment: If it's happening in 3 projects and after every change you make, to me, that sounds like an automated process is caching the routes. If you call `php artisan route:clear` you should be able to freely make changes to your route definitions and see them take effect without needing to recache.

Comment: You are correct so the idea is that if I made php artisan route:cache the request will be routed from cached routes right? And if I made php artisan route:clear the request will be routed from web.php?

Comment: stop running `artisan route:cache` ... you only need this in production, locally you don't cache things like this, otherwise every time you make a change you would have to clear it  ... run `artisan route:clear`

Comment: Caching routes is for performance optimisation when in production. During development you must not cache routes otherwise you will have to `route:clear` and `route:cache` with every change which is not desirable

Comment: Hello, i have the same problem. You found the solution?

Comment: @user2227682 just use `route:clear`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
php artisan route:clear
```

This will clear your route cache and allow you to freely make updates to your routes file without needing to recache. In development, you should not be caching anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vagrant/homestead combo check the date on your machine, if I go on standby for a few hours the time seems to drift.

So any changes I was making to routes, wasn't being picked up and the only thing that would clear it was `route:clear` or `config:clear`

Restarting machine worked but also a `vagrant halt` & `vagrant up` might work too.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `php artisan optimize` instead.